# How to manage movieclip button controls sound on main timeline?

Tags: flash, audio, button, actionscript

I'm having trouble trying to manipulate music using buttons

1. I can't seem to make `music1` autoplay and loop when the movie starts.
2. I want to stop `music1` and play `music2` when I press a button:

   - `music1` in main timeline
   - button to change music is inside a movie clip

so far here is the code I found on the internet but I'm not sure how I can change it to do what I need:

```
var mySound:Sound;
var myChannel:SoundChannel;
var isPlaying:Boolean = false;
var isPaused:Boolean = false;
var p:uint = 0;
var songfile:String;
var songtitle:String;

song1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
song2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
song3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseSound);

function stopSound(myEvent:MouseEvent):void {
    if (isPlaying) {
        myChannel.stop();
        p = 0;
        isPlaying = false;
        isPaused = false;
    }
}

function playSound(myEvent:MouseEvent):void {
    switch(myEvent.target.name) {
        case "song1_btn":
            songfile = "bgm1.mp3";
            songtitle = "one";
            break;
        case "song2_btn":
            songfile = "bgm2.mp3";
            songtitle = "two";
            break;
        case "song3_btn":
            songfile = "bgm3.mp3";
            songtitle = "Three";
            break;
    }
    mySound = new Sound;
    mySound.load(new URLRequest(songfile));
    title_txt.text = songtitle;
    if (isPlaying) {
        myChannel.stop();
        myChannel = mySound.play(0);
    } else {
        myChannel = mySound.play(0);
        isPlaying = true;
    }
}

function pauseSound(myEvent:MouseEvent):void {
    if (isPlaying) {
        p = Math.floor(myChannel.position);
        myChannel.stop();
        isPlaying = false;
        isPaused = true;
    } else if (isPaused) {
        myChannel = mySound.play(p);
        isPlaying = true;
        isPaused = false;
    }
}

title_txt.text = "This text will be replaced.";
```

**Note:** this code is in the main timeline.

Comment: What are those 'music1' and 'music2' you talk about? I don't see them in the code you posted? Are they song files, song names, variables of the type sound...? Also, what do you mean by 'music1' in main timeline?

Comment: oops sorry for the lack of details.. i found this code on the internet and thought maybe its similar to what i wanted to do

what i mean is that, i wanted it to work like this

1. music 1 will automatically play at the start of the movie and loop until i close the window

2. then i have a button inside a movieclip that will change the current music (music1) into music 2

basically, im making a interactive portfolio, where there is background music playing. then i have a page that will play a hymn, so i need a button to change the background music to the hymn, and vice versa

Comment: For 1) Create a movieclip and place the sound file on the frame,

Comment: Please disregard the previous comment, couldn't edit it. Haven't done ActionScript for a long time, but try this: Create a MovieClip and place 'music1' on the first frame of the newly created MovieClip, and put 'stop()' on this frame, create a second frame on the second frame and put 'StopAllSounds'. Then create a third frame and have 'music2' on there. And have 'stop()' on this frame also. The button should do 'MovieClip1.Play()' and this will start 'music2'. And to play 'music1' again, 'MovieClip1.GotoFrame(1)'. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code is similar to what you are looking for, I tried to keep things simple in case you want to modify anything to better suit your needs:

```
var mySound:Sound;
var myChannel:SoundChannel;

//song files
var music1:String="music1.mp3";
var music2:String="music2.mp3";

//initially load and loop music1
loopMusic(music1);

//button to change to music2 inside movieclip
myMovieclip.myButton2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button2_handler);

//button to change back to music1 inside movieclip
//initially disabled since music1 is playing
myMovieclip.myButton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button1_handler);
myMovieclip.myButton1.enabled=false;

function loopMusic(songName:String):void
{
  //stop music currently playing
  if(myChannel)
    myChannel.stop();

  //initialize sound var
  mySound = new Sound();

  //load song
  mySound.load(new URLRequest(songName));

  //set up event listener
  mySound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, songLoaded_handler);

}

function songLoaded_handler(evt:Event):void 
{
//loop loaded song 
    myChannel = mySound.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);
}

function button1_handler(e:Event):void
{
    loopMusic(music1);

    //toggle buttons
    myMovieclip.myButton2.enabled=true;
    myMovieclip.myButton1.enabled=false;


}

function button2_handler(e:Event):void
{
    loopMusic(music2);

    //toggle buttons
    myMovieclip.myButton1.enabled=true;
    myMovieclip.myButton2.enabled=false;


}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried the code and it returned an error

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at trial2_fla::MainTimeline/loopMusic()
 at trial2_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: maybe somethings is missing in the code? i dunno how to solve it.. i appreciate it if u can help me again thanks

Comment: My bad, of course you get error 1009, I just realized I failed to put the line where I initialize the mySound var... I corrected the code and tested it and it works without errors now. There was another line missing so please update all the code before trying it. Sorry about the sloppy copy&paste, hope this helps to solve your problem!

Comment: hi again, i tried the code on a sample movie and its working fine, but when i tried using it on the movie im working on, the autoloop works but the buttons doesnt. it has an error saying     Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at ADIEUXINTERFACE_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: got the problem now.. someone told me that the problem is my structure.. i should have 1 frame for everything.. but i dunno how i can do that..

Comment: Since you seem to have problems with the buttons part, I think you should take a look at some as3 tutorials, for example: http://www.schoolofflash.com/2011/04/tutorial-actionscript-3-buttons/ or http://www.iheartactionscript.com/coding-movieclips-as-buttons-in-as3/ or http://forums.adobe.com/thread/629023

Answer (score 0):

tried editing the code since the buttons are under 2 layers of movieclip.. my mistake.. heres the code but its returning an error when i tried playing the movie

```
var mySound:Sound;
var myChannel:SoundChannel;

//song files
var music1:String="sounds/music1.mp3";
var music2:String="sounds/music2.mp3";

//initially load and loop music1
loopMusic(music1);

//button to change to music2 inside movieclip
mc_university.mc_hymn.myButton2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button2_handler);

//button to change back to music1 inside movieclip
//initially disabled since music1 is playing
mc_university.mc_hymn.myButton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button1_handler);
mc_university.mc_hymn.myButton1.enabled=false;

function loopMusic(songName:String):void
{
//stop music currently playing
if(myChannel)
myChannel.stop();

//initialize sound var
mySound = new Sound();

//load song
mySound.load(new URLRequest(songName));

//set up event listener
mySound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, songLoaded_handler);

  }

  function songLoaded_handler(evt:Event):void 
  {
  //loop loaded song 
  myChannel = mySound.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);
  }

  function button1_handler(e:Event):void
  {
  loopMusic(music1);

  //toggle buttons
  mc_university.mc_hymn.myButton2.enabled=true;
  mc_university.mc_hymn.myButton1.enabled=false;


}

    function button2_handler(e:Event):void
{
  loopMusic(music2);

  //toggle buttons
  mc_university.mc_hymn.myButton1.enabled=true;
  mc_university.mc_hymn.myButton2.enabled=false;


}
```

dunno what went wrong.. even if i put the buttons in the main timeline or inside a movieclip like the original code, it still gives the same error